# Additive Scene loading in Unity Networking

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, multiplayer, unity-networking, unity3d-unet

I have a main scene where my player is loading as i start or join server. On some action of the player i want to load additive scene in my main scene which is loading fine on the client but not across the network. My other clients are unable to watch it. I checked different links [**here**](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/unet-with-additive-scene-loading-and-different-scenes-for-each-client.383468/) and I also found [**this unity Feedback page**](https://feedback.unity3d.com/suggestions/add-additive-scene-loading-to-unet) it seems to me that this(**ADDITIVE SCENE LOADING TO UNET**) feature is not available in unity. Can anyone confirm that additive scene loading in unet is not available then what the alternative?

Answer (score 0):

Additive scene loading is not available in unet. The alternative would be trying to replicate it by network instantiating things. This might be computer intensive, and definitely tedious, but you could instantiate all the objects in the other scene manually if it came to that. That is the only option as far as I'm aware. Maybe photon has an additive option

Comment: Thanks for info which i already know but what is the alternative? details

Comment: @MohammadFaizanKhan As I said, you can make a class that just instantiates a bunch of objects, or explore other networking tools like photon. as for details, I would make a class that takes care of anything that needs to be done (instantiating game objects, changing environment, etc.), and have it run whenever a specific event happens. In my opinion, though, photon is a much easier and powerful tool when it comes to networking.

Comment: in the presence of new unity networking system(unet) i don't think that we require photon as their package is also not updated